# Install and bind an SSL cert in a Windows Server instance running in Docker

Tags: docker, powershell, iis

I have a classic ASP site running in a Docker container. I'm having all sorts of problems installing a certificate.

**What works**

I can install and bind a PFX using the following commands.

```
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cert = Import-PfxCertificate -Password $pwd -FilePath "c:\cert\cert.pfx" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My #-Exportable # optional if i want the private key to be exportable
New-IISSiteBinding -Name MySite -BindingInformation "*:443:sub.mydomain.com" -CertificateThumbPrint $cert.Thumbprint -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\my"  -Protocol "https"
```

Problem is, my private key is there and the password is going to be challenging to keep safe. I could probably use a keystore and pull it dynamically but that seems like a lot. Using a PRX doesn't seem like a great idea, let me know if I'm wrong about that.

**What doesn't work**

I've tried various combinations of cer and crt that I've downloaded from Digicert. They all install fine. Here's a sample command I'm using to install.

`$cert = Import-Certificate -FilePath C:\cert\mycert.cer -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My\`

However, when I try to bind them using the same command as above, `New-IISSiteBinding -Name MySite -BindingInformation "*:443:sub.mydomain.com" -CertificateThumbPrint $cert.Thumbprint -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\my"  -Protocol "https"`, I consistently get the error.

```
New-IISSiteBinding : A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070520)
At line:1 char:1
+ New-IISSiteBinding -Name MySite -BindingInformation "*:443:at ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-IISSiteBinding], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.IIS.Powershell.Commands.NewIISSiteBindingCommand
```

My assumption is, this a permission issue. If I had a full blown Windows instance with a GUI, I could more easily debug, but I have a terminal session on a Docker container. From what I can tell, the cert store on Docker is `cert:\LocalMachine\My` by I can't run a `Get-Acl` at that location so I don't see how I could set permissions here.

**Questions**

- Is this is a permission issue?
- Where are the physical certificates stored so I can grant permission?
- What user does IIS run as on a container?

Comment: Based on the error message you provided: "The specified logon session does not exist", this could be a permissions issue. In Windows Docker containers, IIS typically runs as the "IUSR" user. This account needs to have appropriate permissions to access the certificate store.

Comment: Where is the certificate store on a Docker instance of Windows?

Comment: When using Windows containers, Docker Desktop automatically manages the certificate store. It integrates with the Windows certificate store, so the certificates used inside the container are managed by Windows itself. The official Docker documentation says: Docker recognizes certs stored under Trust Root Certification Authorities or Intermediate Certification Authorities. I'm not an expert in the Docker field, you can check this: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/configure-docker-to-use-ssl-for-a-private-registry-on-windows-10